# JavaFX: ChoiceBox with image and text

Tags: java, css, javafx

I'd like to create a dropdown menu with a JavaFX ChoiceBox where each entry consists of a different icon with a short text next to it. (Like, for example, in a language selector, where you have a little flag on the left and the name of the language on the right.)

What is the best way to do this?

---

**I tried to do it via CSS.** The following almost works, but of course it will set the same icon for all entries:

```
#accChoiceBox .menu-item .label {
    -fx-padding: 0 0 0 30px;
    -fx-background-size: 20px 20px;
    -fx-background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -fx-background-image: url("../resources/images/icon.png");
}
```

So I thought I could just give each entry its own icon via `#accChoiceBox .menu-item:nth-of-type(1) .label` or similar, but none of the selectors I tried worked.

Comment: As far as I know, [JavaFX CSS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html) does not support nth-child (and similar) selectors. Can you use a `ComboBox` instead of a `ChoiceBox`? Then you can write a cell factory which generates the appropriate graphic and text.

Comment: Yes, I can. I will try that and come back later to tell how it turned out. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay, solved the problem by simply using a ComboBox instead of a ChoiceBox (thanks, [James_D](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32334137/javafx-choicebox-with-image-and-text?noredirect=1#comment52542998_32334137)). There are lots of examples and solutions on the web concerning images in ComboBoxes. Anyway, I will just leave my own one here, too.

It will simply give the first entry in the ComboBox `icon_1.png`, the second one `icon_2.png` and so on.

```
comboBox.setCellFactory(new Callback<ListView<String>, ListCell<String>>() {
    @Override
    public ListCell<String> call(ListView<String> p) {
        return new ListCell<String>() {
            @Override
            protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(item, empty);
                setText(item);
                if (item == null || empty) {
                    setGraphic(null);
                } else {
                    Image icon;
                    try {
                        int iconNumber = this.getIndex() + 1;
                        String iconPath = "MyProject/resources/images/icon_" + iconNumber + ".png";
                        icon = new Image(getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(iconPath));
                    } catch(NullPointerException ex) {
                        // in case the above image doesn't exist, use a default one
                        String iconPath = "MyProject/resources/images/icon_na.png";
                        icon = new Image(getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(iconPath));
                    }
                    ImageView iconImageView = new ImageView(icon);
                    iconImageView.setFitHeight(30);
                    iconImageView.setPreserveRatio(true);
                    setGraphic(iconImageView);
                }
            }
        };
    }
});
```